# Webscraping issue where dataframe to csv put output into one cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to help out our soccer coach who is doing some work on helping underprivileged kids get recruited.  I am trying to scrape a "topdrawer" website page so we can track where players get placed. I am not a python expert at all and am banging my head against the wall.  I got some help yesterday and tried to implement - see two sets of code below.  Neither puts the data into a nice table we can sort and analyze etc.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv


max_page_num = 14
max_page_dig = 1 # number of digits in the page number


with open('result.csv',"w", newline='') as f:
    f.write("Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment \n")

for i in range(0, max_page_num):  
   page_num = (max_page_dig - len(str(i))) * "0" +str(i) #gives a string in the format of 1, 01 or 001, 005 etc
   source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=&genderId=m&graduationYear=2020&positionId=0&playerRating=&stateId=All&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=commitments"
   df = pd.read_html(source)
   df = pd.DataFrame(df)
   df.to_csv('results.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a') #'a' should append each table to the csv file, instead of overwriting it.
```

The second method jumbles the output up into one line with /n separators etc

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import csv


max_page_num = 14
max_page_dig = 1 # number of digits in the page number


with open('result.csv',"w", newline='') as f:
    f.write("Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment \n")

for i in range(0, max_page_num):  
    page_num = (max_page_dig - len(str(i))) * "0" +str(i) #gives a string in the format of 1, 01 or 001, 005 etc
    print(page_num)
    source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=&genderId=m&graduationYear=2020&positionId=0&playerRating=&stateId=All&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=commitments"
    print(source)

    url = urllib.request.urlopen(source).read()    

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    #table = soup.table
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    with open('result.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
       for tr in table_rows:
           td = tr.find_all('td')
           row = [i.text for i in td]
           f.write(str(row))
```

in the first version the data is all place on one line and not separated.
The second version puts each page into one cell and splits the pages in half.

Comment: Because page may have many `<table>` so `pd.read_html` never returns one `DataFrame` but list with many `DataFrames`and you have to check which one has your data and then use it.

Comment: but first you have to check if paga doesn't uses JavaScript to create tables. `pandas` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: using `str(row)` you create string with `[ ]` which is incorrect in csv file. You should rather use `",".join(row)` to create correct string. And don't forget to add `\n` at the end because `write()` doesn't add `\n`. But better use `csv` and `writerow()` which may resolved other problems with data - like `,` in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page may have many `<table>` in HTML (sometimes used to create menu or to organize elements on page) and `pandas.read_html()` creates `DataFrame` for every `<table>` on page and it always returns list with all created `DataFrames` (even if there was only one `<table>`) and you have to check which one has your data. You can display every `DataFrame` from list to see which one you need. This way I know that first DataFrame has your data and you have to use `[0]` to get it.

```
import pandas as pd

max_page_num = 15 # it has to be 15 instead of 14 because `range(15)` will give `0-14`

with open('result.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write('Name, Gender, State, Position, Grad, Club/HS, Rating, Commitment\n')

for i in range(max_page_num):  
   print('page:', i)

   page_num = str(i)
   source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=&genderId=m&graduationYear=2020&positionId=0&playerRating=&stateId=All&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=commitments"

   all_tables = pd.read_html(source)
   df = all_tables[0]
   print('items:', len(df))

   df.to_csv('results.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a') #'a' should append each table to the csv file, instead of overwriting it.
```

---

**EDIT:**

In second version you should use `strip()` to remove `\n` which csv would tread as beginning of new row.

You shouldn't use `str(row)` because it creates string with `[ ]` which is not correct in csv file. You should rather use `",".join(row)` to create string. And you have to add `\n` at the end of every row because `write()` doesn't add it.

But it could be better to use `csv` module and its `writerow()` for this. It will convert list to string with `,` as separtor and add `\n` automatically. If some item will have `,` or `\n` then it will put it in `" "` to create correct row.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import csv


max_page_num = 15


fh = open('result.csv', "w", newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(fh)

csv_writer.writerow( ["Name", "Gender", "State", "Position", "Grad", "Club/HS", "Rating", "Commitment"] )

for i in range(max_page_num):
    print('page:', i)

    page_num = str(i)
    source = "https://www.topdrawersoccer.com/search/?query=&divisionId=&genderId=m&graduationYear=2020&positionId=0&playerRating=&stateId=All&pageNo=" + page_num + "&area=commitments"

    url = urllib.request.urlopen(source).read()    

    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        #row = [i.text.strip() for i in td] # strip to remove spaces and '\n'
        row = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in td] # strip to remove spaces and '\n'
        if row: # check if row is not empty
            #print(row)
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

fh.close()
```

Comment: Awesome!  I am still learning so this was immensely helpful and saved me tons of time.  Much appreiciated